# Looping through a large spreadsheet row by row that is filtered and has hidden rows. How do I copy the previous visible rows and make a table?

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

My program works like this:

I have a running total of dollar amounts (from $0 to $260m). Each row has data related to the cost. My objective was to extract each row when it goes up by a budget increment e.g. $5mil, so I would extract the row that has $4.9mil then $9.9mil then $14.9mil (to stay little bit under $5mil) in the running total column. To do this I created a new column that subtracts $5mil from the column with the running total. Starting from $0 running total will give me a negative number until the running total is bigger than the budget increment of $5mil which will then give me a positive number. When it reaches this positive number the running total will be $5+mil but I would want something like $4.9mil. (When it reaches a positive number I add $5mil to the budget increment. I need to extract the previous (last) negative number.

Here is an annotated picture:

[image]

Here is the code I have so far:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Dim number_of_rows As Long
    Dim budget_increment As Long
    Dim rng_data As Range
    Dim prev_visible_row As Object

    number_of_rows = Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng_data = Range("I2:I" & number_of_rows)
    budget_increment = 5000000

    For i = 180 To number_of_rows
        Range("I" & i & ":I" & i) = Range("H" & i & ":H" & i) - budget_increment
        If Range("I" & i).Value > 0 Then
            budget_increment = budget_increment + 5000000
            'find out how to copy the last visible row and paste onto new sheet my attempt at solving this (did not work):
            AutoFilter.Range.Offset(i - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Cells.Copy
            'Sheets("Sheet3").Range("T1").Select
            'Sheets("Sheet3").Paste
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: What is your question? Where are you stuck?

Comment: You need your loop to only look at your visible cells.  Try some of the answers to this question about looping through visible cells only: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37734021/vba-loop-through-visible-cells-only

Comment: You can also just copy the range after it has been filtered, then paste it to the new location

Comment: @FunThomas Please see the annotations in the picture. I want the previous (last) negative number as soon as Column1 reaches a positive number while looping. How do I copy the previous visible row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to the top `Dim inc, counter As Integer: counter = 0`

and change the `If Range("I" & i).Value > 0 Then` to :

```
    If Range("I" & i).Value < Range("I" & (i-1)).Value Then
        For inc = 1 to 999
            If Rows(i-inc).RowHeight > 0 And Range("I" & (i-inc)).Value < 0 Then
                Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A” & (counter + 1) & ":Z" & (counter + 1)).Value = Range("A" & (i-inc) & ":Z" & (i-inc)).Value ' Or something
                counter = counter + 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If
```

Comment: Thank you this works 90%. Although this copies the previous cell value, I wanted to copy the whole row. I tried changing `Range("I" & (i-inc)).Value` to `Range("I" & (i-inc)).Copy` but it just pasted "TRUE" into Sheet3. Any fix to copy the whole row? Also keeping my first IF statement original worked `If Range("I" & i).Value > 0`. I followed everything else; thanks for the suggestion about implementing a counter and checking for row height.

Comment: I fixed it by changing `Sheets("Sheet3").Range("T” & (counter + 1)).Value =  Range("I" & (i-inc)).Value` to `Sheets("Sheet3").Range("T” & (counter + 1)).EntireRow.Value=  Range("I" & (i-inc)).EntireRow.Value` and have suggested the edits to your post.

Comment: @kindofhungry Awesome. To copy the whole row you can use ranges like `Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A” & (counter + 1) & ":Z" &  (counter + 1)).Value =  Range("A" & (i-inc) & ":Z" & (i-inc)).Value` I made the change to the answer above

Comment: @kindofhungry Also, I changed your original `If Range("I" & i).Value > 0` just incase you ever have situation where the values jump from negative to negative without a positive, for ex: -1,100 to -4,900,000 (not sure if possible tho)

Comment: I think if you use `EntireRow.Value` you might not need to used range like `:Z`. (I am not sure about this, still very new to VBA).

Comment: @kindofhungry Using the range and value method is more trustworthy but this may look cleaner : `Rows(i-inc).Copy` and `Sheets("Sheet3").Rows(counter + 1).PasteSpecial Operation:=xlPasteValues`

Comment: @kindofhungry make `counter = 1` at top

Comment: Yes just figured it out as well. I opted to change `counter + 1` to  `counter + 2` instead so its more obvious it starts at row 2